# Input from checkbox not registered in database yet there are no errors [Laravel, inertiajs]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I've spent half day trying to make a simple input *checkbox* type works. I've checked on the controller, database migration table and tried various code to make this works but it didn't. Some code that I tried caused errors in the console and some shows no errors yet when I look on the database table, the value of `is_password` and `is_stamping` is still null. I wonder what am I missing ? Here's part of the code:

```
<div className={'col-span-1'}>
        <InputLabel
          value={'Password PDF'}
          className={'mb-2 font-bold text-base'}
          required={false}
        />
        <TextInput
          type={'checkbox'}
          name={'is_password'}
          className={''}
          value={data.is_password}
          handleChange={ (e) => e.target.value === data.is_password.checked? 1:0 } 
        />
        <InputError message={errors.is_password}/>
      </div>

      <div className="col-span-1">
        <InputLabel
          value={'Stamping'}
          className={'mb-2 font-bold text-base'}
          required={false}
        />

        <TextInput
          type={'checkbox'}
          name={'is_stamping'}
          className={''}
          value={data.is_stamping}
          handleChange={ (e) => e.target.value === data.is_stamping.checked? 1:0 }  
        />
        <InputError message={errors.is_stamping}/>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution...the function at *handleChange* should be change to this,

```
<TextInput
      type={'checkbox'}
      name={'is_stamping'}
      className={''}
      value={data.is_stamping}
      handleChange={ (e) => e.target.checked?  
        setData({ ...data, is_stamping: e.target.checked })
        : setData({ ...data })
      } 
/>
```

Problem solved